# Django: show something else before full request processing ends

Tags: html, django, django-views

I'd like implement a solution where a user can make a request to the backend and since the request takes some time to get the answer from the backed.

I want to render the same page with a loading animation **without javascript**. For this purpose, I set a variable "show_loading" on "true" to display the loading animation via the hmtl-file. The code is as follows:
views.py

```
def UploadView(request):
    show_loading = True
    context["show_loading"] = show_loading
    render(request,'UPLOAD.html',context)
                    
    data = {}
#something else happening, just logical operations

   return render(request,'UPLOAD.html',context)
```

UPLOAD.html:

```
  {% if show_loading %}
   <div class="loader">
   <div class="inner one"></div>
   <div class="inner two"></div>
   <div class="inner three"></div>
   </div>
  {% endif %}
```

The problem is that the render function is not working by the first render line (without return) but with the second render line (with return). So the question is, does render always need return or what I am doing wrong here, that the render does not work without return?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the backend to update the page with a classic Django view, since to communicate with the frontend you need to return a response (yes, `render` must return). The easiest way is to use Javascript: set a simple timer that updates the page if it does not receive a response after a certain time. If you really want to use the backend you need to create a channel between the backend and the frontend, take a look at [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).